# Set row properties for a data bound datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid bound to a object (using MVVM pattern).

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RecordSet}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          Name="ResultGrid">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Path=Id}" Width="Auto"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Foo" Binding="{Binding Path=Foo}" Width="*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Here:

```
RecordSet is a List<Record>.
```

This works fine. The data loads up fine and everything. I wanted to know if there was away for me to set some properties on individual rows i.e. bound a row property to a value in my ViewModel (set each row's Row.IsEnable based on the Record.Enable) 
I am a newbie at WPF.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This should work. Put this style inside your DataGrid.

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>                
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">       
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Enabled}"  Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="0"/>
                    </DataTrigger>                        
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

This will make a row invisble and have no height if the record bound this row is not enabled. The Enabled property in the "{Binding Path=Enabled}" belongs to your Record. I don't know if you have that already, but you'll need something like it.

Comment: this seems a little dangerous to me. maybe it works (I'm not saying it won't), but i would think a row filter is better to hide rows to avoid any wierd edge cases such as cursor keys not working as expected

Answer (score 3):

To follow up on wangburger's answer.
To bind the IsEnabled Property for each DataGridRow to Enabled in Record you can do this

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RecordSet}" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          IsReadOnly="True" 
          Name="ResultGrid"> 
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Enabled}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns> 
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Path=Id}" Width="Auto"/> 
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Foo" Binding="{Binding Path=Foo}" Width="*"/> 
    </DataGrid.Columns> 
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: if you set a row style to `IsEnabled=false` then that row cannot actually be selected at all, neither will the cursor keys skip over it. This may or may not be what you want.

if you want specifically to set `IsEnabled=false` (and I realize you just gave that as an example), but still allow the row to be selectable then you'll need (AFAIK) to set `IsEnabled=false` for each column template.